# JavaFx how to make img setOnMouseClicked goto specific url

Tags: java, javafx

I want my ImageView object on click Event to go to URL within my View what should I do?

`imgView.setOnMouseClicked( e -> {???} );`

Comment: Do you want to change the image contained in `imgView` when clicked on?

Comment: I want to go to any specific URL when I click on this image ??

Comment: And by "go to any specific URL" you meant that page should be shown within some of your views or in user browser?

Comment: within my view not browser

Comment: You can use the [`WebView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/embedded-browser-tutorial/overview.htm) to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want my ImageView object on click Event to go to URL

...is ambiguous, but clarified in the comments:

> within my view not browser

You'll need to use a `WebView` for this.

```
WebView wv = new WebView();
wv.getEngine().load("http://google.com");
```

`WebView` is just a `Node`, so can be added to the scenegraph the same way as anything else.

Comment: thnx bro I edited my description to avoid confusion.